# Can't pack extension: Failed to create temporary zip file during packaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just tried to pack my Chrome extension, and I'm getting the following error from Chrome (and Canary)

```
Failed to create temporary zip file during packaging.
```

Anyone encountered this before?

Edit: I've tried

1. chmoding the directory
2. reinstalling chrome & chrome canary
3. Rolling back to previous version that did pack using git

Comment: Have you tried [enabling logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) in Chrome?

Comment: So you've been able to pack the extension before, but some unknown change has made it that you aren't able to pack now?  I assume you've tried to delete everything and start from scratch?

Comment: Correct. if I put the same files on another computer, they can be packed there.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error, and didn't see any log output from Chrome (on Mac) so no help there.

I use symlinks a lot, and that seemed to be causing the issue. I've had similar issues with Firefox where a mysterious error would clear if I used a real file rather than a symlink.

The `zip` program will copy the files that your links point to, not the symlink itself, so I use it as a cheap way to turn all my symlinks into regular files for WebExtension packaging.

I zipped up the extension directory with:

```
zip -qr extension.zip extension/
```

Moved it somewhere else, unzipped it with:

```
unzip extension.zip
```

Packaged the extension from there and it worked fine with no errors.